# Jekyll: Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/main.scss': Broken pipe

Tags: jekyll, broken-pipe

I am currently trying out Jekyll for my blog website and I have followed the [quickstart guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) on their official documentation. I have installed all prerequisites and followed the `Quick Start` step-by-step.

When attempting to serve, it results in the following error:

```bash
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/main.scss':
                    Broken pipe
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.3.3   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------
```

Here are some additional details about my system and installed dependencies, etc.

- Operating System: Kali Linux

```
ruby -v   
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~]
└─$ gem -v                                              
3.4.20
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~]
└─$ gcc -v
[..]
gcc version 13.2.0 (Debian 13.2.0-13) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~]
└─$ make -v
GNU Make 4.3
[..]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~]
└─$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 13.2.0-13' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-13/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-13 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/reproducible-path/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/reproducible-path/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
```

```
┌──(narwhal㉿WhoAreWe)-[~/Documents/Projects/Tester]
└─$ cat Gemfile.lock 
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.3)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.16.3)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3-aarch64-linux)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3-arm64-darwin)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3-x86-linux)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3-x86_64-darwin)
    google-protobuf (3.25.3-x86_64-linux)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.3.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (>= 0.3.6, < 0.5)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.8, < 4.0)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
    jekyll-feed (0.17.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
      sass-embedded (~> 1.54)
    jekyll-seo-tag (2.8.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.8, < 5.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (2.4.0)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.4)
    listen (3.9.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.4.0)
    minima (2.5.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-feed (~> 0.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.1)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (5.0.4)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rouge (4.2.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-aarch64-linux)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-arm-linux)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-arm64-darwin)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-x86-linux)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-x86_64-darwin)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    sass-embedded (1.71.1-x86_64-linux)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
    terminal-table (3.0.2)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)

PLATFORMS
  aarch64-linux
  arm-linux
  arm64-darwin
  x86-linux
  x86_64-darwin
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
  jekyll (~> 4.3.3)
  jekyll-feed (~> 0.12)
  minima (~> 2.5)
  tzinfo (>= 1, < 3)
  tzinfo-data
  wdm (~> 0.1.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.6
```

I have attempted to reinstall Jekyll, Ruby and so on but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This version of Jekyll hands off the SASS to Dart SASS now - could be some sort of dependency version requirement missing there? Here's a thread to a similar issue if it helps: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/issues/156